# Xamarin axml Linear layout put icon on bottom of screen

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin axml , how do i place image button on below of screen as this picture show.
[image]

This is my current AXML code

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text = "@string/HelloXamarin"
        android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/textView1" />
    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text = "@string/ButtonClick" />
    <Button
        android:text="CALL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Would it be fixed on the Left corner if yes then check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for doing this would be to use a RelativeLayout instead,
Something like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "match_parent">
 <LinearLayout 
   android:orientation = "vertical"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
   <TextView
    android:text = "@string/HelloXamarin"
    android:textAppearance = "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/textView1" />
<Button
    android:id = "@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:text = "@string/ButtonClick" />
<Button
    android:text="CALL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonCall" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:src="@drawable/imageName"
</RelativeLayout>
```